# MySQL get all users, whether or not they have any hours?

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

Trying to get all users, whether or not they have any hours? My LEFT OUTER JOIN still not working..

```
    SELECT tblleaverequest.lqUser,
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 1 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 2 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 3 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 4 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 5 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 6 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 7 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 8 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 9 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 10 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 11 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov',
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 12 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec',
       SUM(tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) AS PaidLeaveTotal

FROM      tblusers LEFT OUTER JOIN tblleaverequest ON tblleaverequest.lqUser = tblusers.username       

WHERE     (tblusers.clr_accrual = '1') AND (YEAR(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())) 
GROUP BY tblusers.username
```

Here are my results, but I need to have the rest of the users w/o hours too.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about you db schema, but seem you just can move one condition from `WHERE` to `ON` clause

```
SELECT tblusers.username,
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 1 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jan',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 2 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Feb',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 3 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Mar',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 4 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Apr',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 5 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'May',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 6 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jun',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 7 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Jul',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 8 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Aug',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 9 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Sep',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 10 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 11 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Nov',
   SUM(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate, '%m') = 12 THEN (tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) ELSE 0 END) AS 'Dec',
   SUM(tblleaverequest.lqHoursPL) AS PaidLeaveTotal

FROM      tblusers 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tblleaverequest 
ON tblleaverequest.lqUser = tblusers.username       
  AND (YEAR(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate) = YEAR(CURDATE())) 
WHERE     (tblusers.clr_accrual = '1') 
GROUP BY tblusers.username
```

Comment: Darn! Took too long typing ;-)

Comment: @Leigh copy-paste! ;-)

Comment: Lol.. no way to compete with that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> WHERE ... (YEAR(tblleaverequest.lqStartDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()))
> ```

If there are no matching in records `tblLeaveRequest`, the date will be `null`. Since a `null` cannot equal anything, those records will be dropped. So you are essentially converting the OUTER JOIN to an INNER JOIN. Move that comparison to the JOIN statement to preserve the OUTER JOIN.

**Update:**

Be sure to grab the username from `tblusers`, since the `tblleaverequest.lqUser` value may be null due to the OUTER JOIN.

```
SELECT tblusers.username 
       , SUM(CASE ......)) AS Jan
       , ....
```

Comment: Leigh, your "prediction" on the username came true.. I made the change to my query per @Alex, but was getting blank users... now working fine. thanks x10!